# Django autocomplete

Tags: jquery, python, django, autocomplete

I am trying to put searchbar with autocomplete function using `django-autocomplete-light`

Here is my view:

```
class SearchAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Trip.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

my form:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    keyword = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Trip.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='search-autocomplete')
    )
```

and my url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(
        r'^search-autocomplete/$',
        SearchAutocomplete.as_view(),
        name='search-autocomplete',
    ),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

However, whenever I am starting to type anything I get `The results could not be loaded`, despite corect queryset object precense. Example:

[image]

Comment: I suspect your url parameter should be the full URL, ie `"/search-autocomplete/"`.